# Зависание работы php5.6-fpm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Столкнулся с проблемой по php5.6-fpm на своем сервере и не могу определить причину. php-fpm работает пару секунд и отключается, удаляя все свои процессы. После рестарта сервиса снова на пару секунд начинает работать и опять отключается. Что можно сделать и где в логах прочесть о причине проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логи находятся в папке `/var/log/php-fpm`, читайте там сообщения об ошибках.